# Excel with VB.NET (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm trying to create an Excel file from VB.net from my first time.
I already added the Microsoft.Office.Excel reference, Import the Microsoft.Office.Interop

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = CType(xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)
    xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Something here"
    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("D:\vbexcel.xlsx")

    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()
    releaseObject(xlApp)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

    MsgBox("Excel file created , you can find the file c:\")

End Sub
```

The error generetad is in the line :

```
   xlWorkSheet = CType(xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)

   Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))
```

Comment: weirdly some sheet names work when you use the text name, but for the worksheet names that throw an exception as indicated above we will have to use the index.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe your version of Excel doesn't speak English.  And "sheet" is a dirty word in the local language, it kinda is in English ;)  Your name is a hint that English is not the default language.  Use the index instead of the name to avoid accidents like this:

```
    xlWorkSheet = CType(xlWorkBook.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
```

Comment: hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh IT Works

Answer (score 2):

This could also be happening because

```
Workbook.Worksheets.Count
```

is less than the number of sheets you use, depending on how your Excel settings are. For me it starts with 3 sheets but for a colleague it starts
with 2 sheets.

So you can call

```
Workbook.Worksheets.Add()
```

to reach the desired number of sheets